# Ember : Build error after installing ember-table

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-table

I am using ember version 2.3.0. I have added ember-table addon in my ember project using ember-cli,

```
ember install ember-table
```

But after adding ember-table, I am not able to build my ember project as it is throwing following error in console,

[image]

When I try to access my project in browser, it is showing following error message.

```
Build error

web-ui/templates/body-table-container.hbs (in C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\tmp\template_compiler-input_base_path-PohadWgB.tmp\0)

Assertion Failed: Using `{{view}}` or any path based on it ('web-ui/templates/body-table-container.hbs' @ L5:C8) has been removed in Ember 2.0

Error: Assertion Failed: Using `{{view}}` or any path based on it ('web-ui/templates/body-table-container.hbs' @ L5:C8) has been removed in Ember 2.0
at new Error (native)
at Error.EmberError (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:4552:21)
at assert (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:1495:13)
at Object.assert (C:\xampp\htdocs\mstack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:4322:34)
at assertPath (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:11608:22)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:11576:7
at Walker.visit (C:\xampp\htdocs\mstack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:18545:7)
at visitors.Program (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:18555:16)
at Walker.children (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:18578:7)
at Walker.visit (C:\xampp\htdocs\stack-ui\spoke\web-ui\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:18546:12)
```

Can anyone help me to find the reason for this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ember-table doesn't seem to support Ember 2.0 as of now because they are still using views which were removed from Ember 2.0. Seems like there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/pull/374) for converting everything to components but it's not merged yet.

You could try using the branch of the pull request or you could try to install the [ember-legacy-views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views) addon which enables views in Ember 2.0 (just until 2.4 though) but I am not sure if the ember-table will work properly with it.

Answer (score 1):

[ember-table 2.0](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table) is in progress. There is already a release v2.0.0-alpha.2 . The old guides are outdated, but people can get familiar with it by checking out the dummy app on master branch!